Which method is best for analysing an existing system when there is a limited number of testers?
I am currently working on a project for developing a ticket management system for a dissertation project. Due to limited interaction with the end users because language barriers and company protocols, I only have access to one user of the product.
the existing system is not a UI feature of their digital products but done through mails sent by end users and resolved by CRM agents. It must be noted that the end users are locals of the area and may not have a very high level of education which led to a need for an integrated module that makes the task of inputting data easier easier for them. The aim is that it will reduce the mistakes in input of data and also reduce the response time.
I want to analyse the constraints of the existing system, however I only know about user journey maps and task analysis in depth.
Is there any other way to analyse the existing system for gaps and/or identify the gaps using user journey maps and task analysis and then compare the two systems with a different method?

There are lots of things you could do here. First 2 that come to mind are:

Heuristic Analysis
There are lots of ticket management systems out there. You could get access to a couple others, map out the User Flows of other systems and do a comparative analysis against the user flow of the system you're working on

Those may not be enough to let you know of any constraints you don't know about though. You could also try a Click Test with non-users, even internal folks like your CRM agents.enter link description here
